# Is it better to maintain pre-exisiting answers or create new answers?

Tags: discussion

Which benefits the site as a whole? Maintaining previous answers or creating new ones?

Consider this.  Games that we play nowadays are rarely the final version.  Most of them have DLC releases, new patch/bug fixes that are released sporadically, or version changes.  Even games that may seem final never really become "final".

As such, answers to a question that may have come during a game's initial stage may become invalid towards a later stage.  As a result, the question becomes "should I edit previous answers to fit the new criteria" or "should I create a new answer to add more information, but in the process lose the answers previously used"?

Thanks, and I appreciate all feedback.

Answer (score 5):

When editing the original meaning of the answer should not change. If the update is large (such as changing a whole mechanic), a new answer is probably better than overhauling an existing answer. If the update simply changes around some values, it's more useful to edit the values in the existing answer.

Comment: What should be done with the old answer? A notice that it's out of date with a link to the new answer?

Comment: A note with the version it applied to seems the most reasonable to me.